# I don't understand what's wrong with my rules

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I had setup my rules in the RealtimeDatabase so that only people who created the content can read or updated it, but unfortunately the rules don't work like that.

I also tried various other rules with less security so the issue doesn't lie in my app.

**These are my rules which don't let me read my own data.**

```
 {
    "rules": {
    "posts": {
       "$uid": {
         ".read": "$uid == auth.uid",
         ".write": "$uid == auth.uid"
       }
     }
   }
}
```

**Code in my app.**

Path: user/uid/info
Value: imageUrl

```
fun getFireBaseValue(Path: String, Value: String): String {
        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(Path).child(Value)
            .addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
                override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
                    val fetchedValue = p0.value.toString()
                }

                override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {
                }
            })
    }
```

I expected a URL i wrote earlier. But instead I get an error: "**DatabaseError: Permission denied**". 
As far as I understand the rules, I should be allowed to read my own  data.

Comment: Please edit the question to show the code that doesn't work the way you expect.  Please explain in detail the contents of any variables used in that code.

Comment: Okay, I hope it is better to understand now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `Path` variable in your code sample is `user/uid/info`, then the rules don't allow access to that location.  The rules only allow per-user access to `posts/uid`.  The path in your rules needs to match the path in your code in order for access to be allowed.